# Storm Track Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, gis, geojson, weather

I wrote a storm track algorithm that calculates the center of a storm over time.  Each storm has a unique _id.  As the storm is passed into the algorithm, the function checks to see if the storm `_id` already exists.  If it does, I make comparisons to its previous position in relation to its current position.

The algorithm is intended to run indefinitely at 2 minute interval.  Data logged in `StormHistory()` is  saved in memory, while the storm track data is saved to a database.

Is there a better way to do this?

Any suggestions on removing a storm from the object if it no longer exists?

```py
class StormHistory():
    pass

class StormTrack:
    _storm = {}

    def storm_track(self, feature=None, validTime=None):
        _id = feature._id

        if _id not in self._storm.keys():
           self._storm[_id] = StormHistory()
           x = self._storm[_id] 

           x... init new storm

        else:
           x = self._storm[_id]
           x... process data
```

Comment: Is the self._storm dictionary there for correctness purposes, or is it just to speed up the algorithm? If the latter, you could perhaps use an LRU cache to evict data which is not accessed for some time.

Comment: Thanks, this was more or less what I was looking for.  I'm unfamiliar with LRU cache, I'll have to read up.